# Show waiting cursor while starting and loading application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to show waiting cursor while my application initializes after clicking on exe file.
My code is below

```
public MainWindow(string FileName):this()
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    //some init code
}
```

But cursor does change only for a moment of second. How to change it for the whole period my `some init code` executes?

**UPD**: instantiation of the main window looks like this in `Program.cs`

```
mainWindow = new MainWindow(args[0]);
 Application.Run(mainWindow);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
//Set the cursor to appear as busy
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

---Execute your code-------

//Make the Cursor to default
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: Are you close one windows form and open another form inside the code?

Comment: No forms are displayed in this code. This is initialisation of the main window.

Comment: Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
InitializeComponent();
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
seems like you are doing this. I also tried this didnt work. If you really needs to show a waiting, what my suggestion is show a welcome screen.While you perform the other init taks of the main form

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing a lot of stuff in form's constructor is not very desired.

Also users will not be very happy watching wait cursor instead of your form. Good practice is to inform user about whats happening in your application. I'd prefer to see form with message `Initializing... please wait` instead of thinking that your application has some problems and it just can't start quickly like all other `exe` files.

[Marek Dzikiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/698347/marek-dzikiewicz) suggestion is correct, if you want to leave things as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as given below

```
//Set the Cursor when app begins 
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

//write your Code here 

//Change the Cursor to Default 
Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

I hope this could help you :-)

Comment: No. It works only when window is loaded and displayed. In my case window is just loading.

Answer (score 0):

be sure that your form is Enabled

```
this.Enabled = true;
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
.....
```